# An issue that connects to the wrong url when executing a .url shortcut file

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

When the .url shortcut file is executed, an error occurs because a strange character is appended to the end of the URL other than the specified URL.

I can't figure out why '%20 --disable-renderer-accessibility' is appended to the end of the url.

For example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) -> [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) %20 --disable-renderer-accessibility

In this way, additional '%20 --disable-renderer-accessibility' is added to all urls, resulting in a url not found error.

Both Chrome and Edge have the same error.

## I checked the following things, but it didn't work

- Reset Edge settings
- Check if the "--disable-renderer-accessibility" parameter is added to the executable file

Any advice on which part to check?

Comment: Switch off any *accessibility features* in Chrome OS and browsers. See https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/128103339/web-accessibility-getting-checked-off-in-accessibility?hl=en and https://www.techthirsty.com/what-is-google-chrome-helper-renderer-and-how-to-disable-it/ for Chrome *browser* issues with and use of --disable-renderer-accessibility

Comment: It was caused by a bug in a specific security program. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Explain what security tool caused the issue and make it an answer -- get credit for answering your own question, and help others who have that issue.